# Kotlin class cannot findViweById

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, findviewbyid

maybe there is a simple reason. I cannot find it...
My findViewById does not find any IDs of my project. So, R.id.name cannot be found, same for R.layout.item.

This is my code:

```
class RVAdapter(persons: List<Person>?): RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder>() {
    inner class PersonViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var cv: CardView
        var personName: TextView
        var personAge: TextView

        init {
            cv = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv)
            personName = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name)
            personAge = this.itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_honor)
        }
    }

    var persons: List<Person>? = null

    init {
        this.persons = persons
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return persons!!.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): PersonViewHolder {
        val v: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false)
        return PersonViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(personViewHolder: PersonViewHolder, i: Int) {
        personViewHolder.personName.text = persons!![i].name
        personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons!![i].honor)
    }

}
```

The IDs are in a XML file definitly excactly like in the code.
I put

```
 buildFeatures{
        viewBinding=true
    }
```

to my gradle file but it doesn´t work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "cannot be found" mean here? Are you importing the right `R`?

Comment: You're not using View Binding here at all (no `ItemBinding.inflate` or referencing views on the resulting `ItemBinding` object) so that's irrelevant. Does `R.layout.item` contain the `person_name` and `person_honor` `TextView`s? Like laalto says, check if you've imported the `R` file for your project - try deleting the import line, hover over one of your IDs in the code and let Android Studio reimport it. Try Clean & Rebuild in the Build menu, or if that doesn't work, Invalidate Caches / Restart in the File menu. And it shouldn't matter, but try `itemView` instead of `this.itemView`

Comment: Are the IDs in the `R.layout.item` XML file (`item.xml`) or in some other XML file? Can you add the contents of `item.xml` to your question?

Comment: @cactustictacs deleting thie R-import does the trick. After that, AS imported the right one. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove R package and re-import it.** May be there is the problem while we copy paste the codes.

Or you can use binding in your adapter -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-view-binding-in-recyclerview-adapter-class-in-android/

Comment: Thanks! This was excactly the right answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Holder Class**

```
 inner class PersonViewHolder(val binding: LayoutItemBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

**onCreateviewHolder override method**

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PersonViewHolder{
   return PersonViewHolder(
            LayoutItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )}
```

**onBindViewHolder override method**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PersonViewHolder, position: Int) {
  
       holder.binding.name.text="what you need"      
 }
```